# App should not start with its first activity

Tags: android

We have a very large project in android,Its running proper on the device, but when any call aur msg come on the device,The app start again by its first login page.
but it should start by the where it was before coming the call.

What changes should i make in this.

Thanks

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Are you talking about saving the current activity in its current state and starting it again in that activity?

Comment: do u want any one of the activities of your project to be the Main Activity so that the application starts from that activity?

Comment: see my app related to money transaction ,when any call come its throw me on the login page,but i want it should again start with previous state.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle) and saving instance state on the same page.